# Grunt: change file extension at build

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I would like to write a Grunt task that, during build, will copy all .html files that I have and make an .asp version of it in /dist as well.

I have been trying to use [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) to accomplish this, and here's what I have:

```
copy: {
  //some other tasks that work...

  //copy an .asp version of all .html files
  asp: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
      src: ['{,*/}*.html'],
      dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
      option: {
        process: function (content, srcpath) {
          return srcpath.replace(".asp");
        }
      }
    }]
  } //end asp task
},
```

I know that the `process` function is not actually correct... I've tried a few different regex to make it work to no avail. When I run the `asp` task, the Grunt CLI says that my it has copied 2 files, but they're nowhere to be found. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that using `rename` function.

For example:

```
copy: {
  //some other tasks that work...

  //copy an .asp version of all .html files
  asp: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
      src: ['{,*/}*.html'],
      dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
      rename: function(dest, src) {
         return dest + src.replace(/\.html$/, ".asp");
      }
    }]
  } //end asp task
},
```

This should works.

Comment: Indeed the `rename` method works, though by looking at the Grunt docs closer, I discovered you can also accomplish a simple file extension change using the `ext` property like so: `ext: '.asp'`.

Comment: Note that you might want to join the dest and src parameters using `path.sep()`, because now you join the file and folder without the slashes `somefoldersomefile.asp` instead of `somefolder/somefile.asp`.